# How can I set a compiler warning (GNU GCC) when overwriting a weak function

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Library functions have the weak attribute set by default (see [1]) and could be "overwritten" with functions having the same signature by accident.
For example `printf` internally calls `fputc` and I could easily declare one of my functions `int fputc(int, FILE *)`.
If that happens, I would like to receive a compiler warning.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to warn me in case of overwriting a weak function?

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: It won't be a compiler warning, but a linker warning. BTW GCC3.2 is an encient -not conforming to current C11 & C++14 standards- compiler, current (march 2016) version is [GCC5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) so you should *upgrade* your `gcc`

Comment: You *are allowed* to *redefine* `fputc`, provided your definition is conforming to the standard (and that may be tricky)

Comment: **Why do you ask?** and what is the actual problem you want to solve? Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)... So please **edit your question** to explain more and motivate it

Comment: I finally downvoted the question because it is not motivated (and I suspect some confusion) and not very clear.

Comment: Actually, it is unlikely that a library function would be overwritten by accident. First, developers are expected to know the C standard library (and won't reuse a name defined in the standard by accident). Second, even if they redefine a function, it is unlikely to have the same signature as the one required by the standard. Other redefinitions -with the good signature- won't be accidental, but on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(I am guessing you are on Linux, and compiling and linking your application as usual, in particular with the `libc.so` *dynamically linked*)</sup>

> Library functions have the weak attribute set by default

This is not always true; on my system `fputc` is not a weak symbol:

```
% nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so|grep fputc
000000000006fdf0 T fputc
0000000000071ea0 T fputc_unlocked
```

(if it was weak, the `T` would be a `W`, and indeed `write` is weak)

BTW, redefining your own `fputc` (or `malloc`) is *legitimate* (and could be useful, but is very tricky), provided it keeps a semantic conforming to the standard. More generally weak symbols are expected to be redefinable (but this is tricky).

> Is there a way to tell the compiler to warn me in case of overwriting a weak function?

**No** (the *compiler* cannot warn you *reliably*).

Since **the** only **thing which could give you some warning is** not the compiler (which does not know which particular `libc` would be used at runtime, you might upgrade your `libc.so` after compilation) but the linker, and more precisely **the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)**, that is [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html). And the warnings could reliably only be given at runtime (because the `libc.so` might be different at build time and at run time). Perhaps you want `LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK`.

If you are ready to spend weeks working on a solution, you might consider using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) with your own *MELT* extension and customize a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to emit a warning when a weak symbol from the `libc` available at compile time (which might not be the same `libc` dynamically linked at runtime, so such a check has limited usefulness) is redefined.

Perhaps you might use some [`LD_PRELOAD` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick).

Also, if you linked statically your application, the linker could give you diagnostics if you redefine a `libc` function.

Read also Drepper's [*How to Write a Shared Library*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) & Levine's [*Linkers & loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.